# Why am I receiving an unused extension error on a dynamic AMP page?

Tags: amp-html

From the AMP validator I am getting the following error.

> The extension 'amp-date-picker' was found on this page, but is unused. Please remove this extension.

This is a dynamic page so sometimes the datepicker will appear on the page and sometimes it will not.

The AMP docs say the script needs adding to the head, so this means that sometimes there will be a scenario where there is no datepicker, but the script is still included.

As I do not think I should be adding this script in with the component HTML, what are my options to fix this error?

Thanks
David

Comment: Some other extensions, such as amp-position-observer, must also not be included when unused. "Why" could be to ensure performance if I have to guess. How is this page "dynamic," from server generation, or dynamic (with amp-list for example) updates?

Comment: From server.  The markup is in a template, sometimes there are dates that require a datepicker and sometimes there are not.

Comment: I used a conditional template to include the extension script. Ugly but the only way that works for me.

Answer (score 0):

You're getting the error due to performance reasons as most components either ignore or warn instead of throwing an error like this. You should be checking your content server-side and dynamically including the script it only if there's a need for it.

This is an example of something similar in PHP (Bolt CMS) which I built for a client a while ago, in the page head it checks for the inclusion of the `amp-youtube` tag in the body before including the script. You'll need to use whatever language you're using, of course.

```
{% set body = record.body|ampraw %}
{% if 'amp-youtube' in body %}
  <script async custom-element="amp-youtube" src="https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0/amp-youtube-0.1.js"></script>   
{% endif %}
```

You can view the validation rules for amp-date-picker [here](https://github.com/ampproject/amphtml/blob/master/extensions/amp-date-picker/validator-amp-date-picker.protoascii).